# use variable inside include/input

Tags: include

I would like to use a variable so I can define which file to include at compile-time (argument passed to LaTeX - see below).

Problem here is that I cannot insert document name with "_", without crashing everything. Is thez a simple way to perform such task?

#### Command line used

```
 pdflatex "\def\testpath{my\_document}\input{my_tex_document}"
```

#### Below is a minimal example of my LaTex document

```
 \documentclass{article} 

 \title{Librairie \testpath}
 \author{Author}

 \begin{document}

 \section{Insertion of \testpath}
 \include{lib_12/\testpath}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: The simple way would be to not have underscores in your filenames?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following command:

```
pdflatex --jobname 'my_document' my_tex_document
```

This will produce a `my_document.pdf` which makes more sense to me.
You can then also use `\jobname` to access the file name without any issues with underscores. The content of that macro is already detokenized.

```
 \documentclass{article} 

 \title{Librairie \texttt{\jobname}}
 \author{Author}

 \begin{document}

 \section{Insertion of \texttt{\jobname}}
 \input{lib_12/\jobname}

 \end{document}
```

You should then always make sure that you don't use `\input{\jobname}` and compile the document without the `--jobname` argument. Otherwise you create an endless loop.

If you need this to only compile certain chapters of a document (which are all included using `\include`) use the following command instead. Here an example of compiling the introduction of a thesis only:

```
pdflatex --jobname introduction '\includeonly{introduction}\input{thesis}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
pdflatex "\edef\testpath{\detokenize{my_document}}\input{my_tex_document}"
```